# Serial Servo Controller using Basic Stamp

Tags: servo, basic, basic-stamp

How can you control a Servo using a Basic Stamp?

Comment: http://forums.parallax.com/forums/default.aspx?f=6&m=164400

Answer (score 4):

Servos' positions are determined by a pulse width signal with a repetition rate of typically 50Hz, so one pulse every 20ms.

[image]

The servo's neutral position (halfway) agrees with a 1.5ms pulse width. Shorter pulses will rotate the servo to the left, longer pulses to the right. So all you have to do is periodically create pulses. [This document](http://www.parallax.com/Portals/0/Downloads/docs/books/sw/Web-SW-v2.1.pdf#page=156) has a servo control demo on page 146. The code used in this demo is simply

```
PULSOUT Servo, (pWidth */ PwAdj)  ' move the servo
PAUSE 20                          ' servo refresh delay
```